# Is there a difference between "I'll go and fetch it for you" & "I'll fetch it for you"?

Tags: word-usage

> [fetch](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fetch?q=fetch): to go to where somebody/something is and bring them/it
>   back
>
> fetch somebody/something: to fetch help/a doctor
>
> *The inhabitants have to walk a mile to fetch water.*

I heard people say "*I'll go & fetch it for you*".

Since "**fetch=go to ... & bring it back**", so I would think "**go**" is unnecessary in "*I'll go & fetch it for you*".

So, we can just say "*I'll fetch it for you*".

Is there a difference between "*I'll go and fetch it for you*" & "*I'll fetch it for you*"?

Comment: "I'll fetch it for you" describes a dedicated task for a specific purpose:  I'll go to where it is and bring it back.  "I'll go and fetch it for you" is used in the same way, but it somewhat implies two actions or purposes.  Going is implied to not be trivial or incidental, it is more like a task in and of itself.  "Fetch" becomes a supplementary task of bringing the item back.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+and+fetch+it%2C+fetch+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20and%20fetch%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfetch%20it%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

There is not a functional difference, but it might imply a difference in the disposition of the speaker. The one who includes "go" might intend to ensure that you recognize that (s)he is doing you a favor. It is highly contextual.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

"Go and fetch it" implies that "it" is farther away, often in another room. Either use is fine though.

Answer (score 0):

I'll fetch it for you.

I'll go and fetch it for you.

Both the sentences are grammatical and have the same meaning except that the second sentence is informal.

In spoken English, you use the verb go with "and" plus another verb to intensify or emphasize the purpose of doing something. Look at the following sentence:

Right. It's five o'clock. I'd better go and fetch my mother from the station (Cambridge).

However, the use of the fetch without "go and" is more common.